# Is it correct to say "Be careful of the bits sticking up. They may poke you in the eye"?

Tags: word-usage, word-request, phrase-usage, phrase-request

[image]

Your child made a ring out of a twist tie but for some reasons, the 2 ends of the tie were not folded and stuck up as shown in the picture.

Is it correct to say "**Be careful of the bits sticking up. They may poke you in the eye**"?

Comment: I would go with **be careful of the ends (or end bits) sticking up (or sticking out). If your child was old enough, **protruding**.

Comment: The sentence is fine for the general case when there are many bit sticking up. For this example, with only the two end bits, I agree with @RonaldSole.

Comment: @RonaldSole's suggestion is nonsense, as it is written.  Perhaps he could clarify it and make it a single complete, grammatical sentence?   There is nothing wrong with the example sentence in OP whatsoever.  It is in every way better than what is written in the comments so far.  ("If your child was old enough, protruding" - what??)